# Does RecyclerView does layuot processing stuff for the elements which it has drawn already when drawing new element?

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

What exactly I am confused is that RecyclerView has a method setHasFixedSize(true) what exactly happens when this method is used on recyclerview instance. Does it recalculate layout stuff or the elements which it has already drawn.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.